# combining middle two columns in the third row

Tags: html, html-table

I want to combine the middle two columns in the third row.
But the columns are not combined in the third row.

what should I do ??
what is the error exactly in my code??

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
}

/* added by editor to visualize the issues */
table {
  border-spacing: 0.5em;
}

td {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you put a picture of your desired table .

Comment: @SuryaNeupane the question actually is very clear (I had to reread and check again). If you look carefully at the rendered output you see that in the 3rd row is a collapsed cell, and the table is not showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want. I have only added a fourth row for test.

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='1'></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan='1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While this answers the questions, it is written more as a commentary question. Nonetheless, it is not a clean or good solution to add new table cells only for the purpose of correcting a layout issue. This is not accessible and not semantically correct. You have better tools that can solve this issue on the CSS-level instead of adding unused nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the way that table cell width is defined or calculated. The [MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) states:

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

The easiest fix is to remove the width of the table cells. Then add a specific width to the table itself and use `table-layout: fixed;` which will equally assign the the width to the columns and not based on the first row:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
}

/* added by editor to visualize the issues */
table {
  border-spacing: 0.5em;
}

td {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

/* add this */
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```